# from list to combobox

Tags: vb.net, list, combobox

My goal is to take user inputted Column information on one form and put it in a combobox on form 2.  Im really new to coding and vb.net, please keep it for dummies.  This is what I have so far on one form.

```
Public Class CrewDatabaseForm
    Public Shared CrewList As List(Of String)

    Private Sub CrewDatabaseForm_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        Dim CL As New List(Of String)
        Dim CLPure As New List(Of String)
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            CL.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        Next
        CLPure = CL.Distinct
        CrewList = CLPure
    End Sub

    Private Sub CrewDatabaseForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

DataGridView1 is just a DataGrid I dragged from the toolbox.  Im trying to pass the first column into a list, make it distinct, then pass it to a public list for this form to get a hold of:

```
Public Class NewWellForm
    Private Sub NewWellForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(CLPure.Item(1))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here Im trying to put the list into Combobox1

The CLPure here is underlined swith squigglies so it will not work.  What am I doing wrong?  Also, I keep finding myself struggling to convert from list to array to combobox to column to etc.  Is there any good consistency, syntax, or resource for learning how to convert between these dataholders?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since your `CrewList` field is `Shared`, you should be able to access it from the other form like this:

```
Private Sub NewWellForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(CrewDatabaseForm.CrewList.ToArray())
End Sub
```

The `AddRange` method allows you to add multiple items at once, but it needs you to give it an array.  Since `CrewList` is a `List(Of String)`, rather than array, you need to convert it to an array before giving it to the `AddRange` method.  Conveniently, the `List(Of String)` class has a `ToArray` method which makes the conversion very easy.

Comment: Thank you, however there must be something wrong with how I've declared CLPure above.  Any help for this?  I keep getting the error 'CLPure is not declared'

Comment: `CLPure` is local to the `CrewDatabaseForm_FormClosed` method, so you will not be able to use it from anywhere else.  That's why in my answer, I said to use `CrewDatabaseForm.CrewList` when you are in the `NewWellForm_Load` method.